# MongoLab and Elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, playframework-2.2, mlab

My Mongo database is hosted at MongoLab. I'd like to use ElasticSearch as a full text search engine on top of my DB.

As I understand MongoDB needs to run as a replica-set, but I don't have any control on how the database run. I'm currently using the 500mb free plan.

On the top of that, I'm using the scala playframework.

Was anyone successful with those technologies and services?

**Update:**

Finally I'm not using MongoDB anymore, and went straight for a ElasticSearch solution.
I found this nice cloud host providing a 500MB free plan http://facetflow.com/

It was very useful for my development.

I didn't find any satisfying Scala library for ES, therefore I'm using Dispatch and make direct http requests to the ES instance.

I hope that someone will find this useful.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Looking for similar issue

Comment: Not yet, I'm still investigating on alternatives, as I want to avoid deploying stuff myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note ... MongoHQ has oplog support with their MongoDB Elastic Deployments ... those could help you with using Elastic Search and River.

http://blog.mongohq.com/elastic-deployments-now-with-oplog-access/

Comment: Thanks for the note!
Unfortunately this feature is not accessible through the free plan. I'll like to test before subscribing :-)

Comment: If you want to try elastic deployments, I am sure that MongoHQ would be happy to send you a coupon for a free month.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into this too deeply, but you might want to check out Searchly http://www.searchly.com/features/ . The features mention

> Built-in crawler for crawling web pages and databases. (Currently MongoDB)

If you try this out, please let me know how it goes.  I will do the same.

Comment: Please let us know how it goes with Searchly MongoDB integration. We are open to all suggestion and feedback at support.searchly.com

Comment: Thanks for the link!
It looks interesting how they do not depend on Mongo's oplog but it seems that they copy and sync the whole mongo database into Searchly, which looks weird to me.

In any case I'll give it a try!

Comment: Here's a feedback: I tried searchly's crawler. It is very easy to setup, but we have little control on its settings. For instance the crawler will crawl the DB every 7 days, which does not cover my need unfortunately. Anyhow, the approach is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I haven't tried searchly, but I was able to start a MongoDB instance in replica mode on OpenShift.

I have also an Elastic Search server running on the same OpenShift "gear".

Now I need time to try connecting those two together, and then the fun will start :-)

Comment: So running MongoDB in replica mode is not feasible on OpenShift due to its storage limit (1gb for the free plan). Once that MongoDB replica set is initialized, it consumes 22gb (with the smallfiles option)! I had no choice than running MongoDB and ES on my local machine.